# I need.setText parameter to be recognized as method , not as a string

Tags: java, android, parameters, settext

I have a problem with the following code:

```
question1.setText("question1_" + question_number() + "()");
```

I have multiple methods that return a string value and are named "question1_x" (x is a number) and the method question_number returns a random number. 
When i run the code like this the "question1" text is set to "question1_x()" , but what i need it to do is set the text as the "question1_x()" method returns it. Simply i like ["question1_" + question_number() + "()"] to be seen by ".setText" as a method and not as a string.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Java won't let you do this unless you resort to reflection. **Reflection is almost certainly the wrong solution to this problem.**

Any time you want to have numbered methods and/or fields, step back and consider using a proper collection (say, a list) instead. Start by replacing your numbered methods with a single method that takes a number:

```
String question1(int questionNumber)
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this right, you want to call a method inside setText by its name. It can't be done the way you're trying to do it.
You need to use Reflections Api. Look at the example below:

> Class myClass = Class.forName("");
>
> Method m = myClass.getMethod(""question1_" + question_number()", (Class[]) null);
>
> Object retVal = m.invoke(object_to_invoke_on, arguments);
>
> setText(retVal);

However, this has performance penalties. It'll be 2-3 times slower than a normal method call. In your case you can avoid this altogether by designing it right.

Comment: As I said in my answer, reflection is the wrong solution to this problem. The existing design is flawed and should be fixed.

Comment: I agree with you. Hence, I have the note at the bottom.